# Opening C++ project in VS2003 with preproject section solution items

Tags: c++, visual-c++, projects-and-solutions

I have inherited a C++ project which probably written in VC++ or even before that which was then converted into some later version of Visual Studio.  I do not have any documentation, nor have been I been told what version of VS was used to unsuccessfully upgrade the project.  My requirements are to now upgrade the project (compile and run) in VS.Net 2003 and of course fix a list of bugs.  So far I have been able to fix in correct references and update the SLN file in notepad to open in VS.Net 2003 Pro edition.  However there is one project with preProject section with references to a bunch of batch, a vsd, and a WSE (Wise Script I presume) files which I cannot figure out.

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{7F317834-B915-4666-9882-64E4C8E6CF11}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        Build\file1.bat = Build\file1.bat
        ...
        Build\Project1.vsd = Build\Project1.vsd
        Build\Project.wse = Build\Project.wse
        #more batch file referecnes
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

Before I used to get the error all the time but now I can open all the project but the "Solution Items" section above still causes the project not installed error:
"The application for project  is not installed. Make sure the application for the project type () is installed."

Is there a way I can fix the solution file given above to open and compile the solution? I have each and every file listed in the SLN in its correct location?  Also can someone explain what exactly is this preProject portion for and what will happen to all the files that are referenced above? TIA for any help.